# Run multiple SQL scripts with oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Right now I'm dropping, creating and then running scripts for several database several times each day. It's getting a little tedious.

I've simple scripts from dropping and creating databases and additional scripts that writes data to the DBs.

I run these scripts through oracle SQL developer.  Is there a way I can run all of these scripts at the same time.  Like in a batch file or another tool?  I.e

- Drop existing DBs
- Create DBs
- Run scripts for DBs

Haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: Create a .sql file with all the script in the order you want, open the .sql file on the SQL Developer and hit on run button

Comment: Yes, Oracle's client tool for use with batch programs is SQL*Plus. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a scheduled job in sql developer. See bellow steps to create a job:

1- From your connection in sql developer select scheduler. In right click select "New Job ...".

[image]

2- In opened window you should select "PL/SQL Block" for "Type of Job" then write a block just like I wrote in bellow picture. Then you should select "Repeating" and insert intervals and start and end dates:
[image]

3- Keep in the mind that "Enable" box should be checked.

4- click on "Apply". Your Job will be ran based on intervals and start date you inserted.

Comment: A tip! You can create a procedure including all of your codes, for example "Prc_DCR", and as "Type of Job" /"Stored Procedure" select just "Prc_DCR".

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll play around with this but looks like it's exactly what I need